# Is asking what being is to make being an entity (*das Seiende*)?

Tags: heidegger, being-and-time

I am reading "Being and Time", and I do not understand this :

-Is asking what being is to make being an entity (*das Seiende*) ?

Thus : Doesn't what Heidegger is doing consist in making being the entity that is being?

Comment: Maybe useful [Heideggerian terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology#Dasein)

Comment: Entity is meant to be named to be recognized to be ready-to-hand, be it natural, artificial or legal, thus its namability implies its fixed characteristics and dispositions. While being in itself as dasein is entirely different, as discloser it continually opens up the world, its thrownness and chosen possibilities dynamically define the said being-with in the context of its caring. So "Is asking what being is to make being an entity?" is challenging the old philosophy that treats being as just another object rather than as the very concept that shapes our understanding of everything else...

Comment: maybe the question is about language. does "Being" occur independent of whether or not we formulate thoughts about it? is "Being" merely an item of language? or does the term "Being" create something that shows up as an entity? if the latter, then it's probably a sublimation or aufheben of our need for others, imvho

Comment: eye don't know wtf is wrong with my analysis. pfft. tbh, i do think that a reification would involve booth language and (social) reality, not just one or the other. idk

Comment: Re your edit this is unavoidable in language, just on a more abstract level than being the usual abstract level of either prototype based or class based entity, as he famously proclaimed '*let being be*', though this 'being' is purely dynamic in nature along with a sailing emotion in constant absolute motion by opening itself up for the ownmost actuality-not-possibility of death out of the 'they-self' to achieve a shocking individuation of Dasein facing its own psychic 'uncanny', a uniting of contradictions. Time bases and induces Da (here or there) beings unlike present-at-hand equipments...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the basis of a criticism of Heidegger's *Sein und Zeit*, namely that he is involved in a philosophical fallacy called *reification* (a term that seems to be used approvingly by math educators).  Thus, Carnap:

> Rudolf Carnap accused Heidegger of offering an "illusory" ontology, criticizing him for committing the fallacy of reification (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger#Reception_by_analytic_and_Anglo-American_philosophy)).

In more detail, when Heidegger asks: "What do we mean by the sky *being* blue?" and then goes on to analyse the "being" of the sky as a new category, he is skipping a few steps.  My personal opinion is that Heidegger succeeded in reinvigorating continental philosophy by putting the soul back into it so to speak, but a rather abstract one (also, a soul/Sein attached to every brick etc., not merely to living creatures).

Comment: +1 Raising categorization and metaphysics as the importance of the contribution.

Comment: @JD, that's an intriguing comment.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the great philosophers don't simply extend a linguistic framework, but rather they offer insights into how to construct one's reality. In this case, one of the fundamental question is "What is an entity?" to which one might get an austere ontology like Quine or a populous one by Meinong. In the case of the Continental tradition, Heidegger argues that the question cannot be answered well without a reference to the person asking and answering the question. I could be wrong, but the animus you attribute to object is a recognition that objects are part of subjects.